# How do I create a function that assembles data into a dictionary and then returns the values of a particular key, given as an argument?

Tags: python, function

Suppose I have a function:

```
def data_fetch():
# The function assembles this dictionary from various sources:

    my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3],
               'b': [4, 5, 6],
               'c': [7, 8, 9]
}
```

And I want to be able to call the function with any combination of arguments `a`, `b`, and/or `c` and have the function return `my_dict['a']`, or `(my_dict['a'], my_dict['b'])`, etc., depending on the arguments entered when the function is called.

How do I do this? Or what is a more effective/canonical way of setting this up?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem so far?

Comment: I tried using optional arguments `a=False`, `b=False`, `c=False`, and I tried some stuff with *args, but I was having a hard time understanding how to use those for my use case, particularly with how to then specify the return statement. I can get any one thing to return, but I was struggling with a way to work with the different possible input combinations. I also wanted to know if there was a canonical way of doing this, because I don't have much formal CS training and this seems like a task that might be fairly common.

Answer (score 2):

one way of doing it is to use `varargs`:

```
def data_fetch(*args):
    my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3],
               'b': [4, 5, 6],
               'c': [7, 8, 9]}
    return tuple(my_dict[arg] for arg in args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is by using [`dict.__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```
def data_fetch(*args):
    my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3],
               'b': [4, 5, 6],
               'c': [7, 8, 9]}
    return tuple(map(my_dict.__getitem__, args))
```